# how to use mailchimp to submit emails via ajax?

Tags: ajax, mailchimp

How can I use the mailchimp API to submit emails via AJAX?

I've looked at the documentation but I cannot find any mention of using Mailchimp with JQuery.

Comment: what you need to do is have your API integration for mailchimp setup properly on your server, then you need to send form data via AJAX to your server and then use that in the way you want for mailchimp

Comment: Here is a well documented code for reference http://www.webylog.com/2015/12/02/mailchimp-integration-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

apiIntegration.php

```
function mailChimpAPI()
{
    //use $key from $_POST as variable name and assign the $val to that var's value
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    {
        ${$key} = $val;
    }

    //mailchimp API call to the subscribe method
    if($mailchimp->subscribe($fname, $lname, $email))
    {
        return true; //on success
    }
        return false; //on failure to subscribe properly
}
```

myJS.js

```
//make sure to use a closure to ensure the $ sign is being used in the proper context (jQuery)
(function($)
{
    //shorthand AJAX call using '$.post'
    $.post('/apiIntegration.php', {fname: "Bob", lname: "Jones", email: "bj@me.com"}, function(data)
    {
        console.log(data); //log out the information returned from server.
    }
}(jQuery));
```

This is mostly just psudo code, so take it with a grain of salt. I hope it points you in the right direction!

Comment: I'm running everything on the client side. I need pure ajax.

Comment: please share your code. what languages are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the MailChimp API Directly via AJAX, as it does not support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You'll either need to use a back-end script to proxy your calls or, if all you need is subscription, you can try to spoof a MailChimp signup form.